# Small-parameter expansion in a scattering theory of resistive charge transport in metals

Tags: electrical-resistance, scattering, perturbation-theory, metals

In metals the equilibrium configuration of the electrons is a Fermi
sea of occupied states centered symmetrically about wave vector $k =
0$.  In a simple Drude-like transport theory, a small electric field
$E$ shifts the Fermi sea away from $k = 0$ by $\delta k$, yielding a
steady state where the electron drift due to $E$ is compensated on
average by scattering processes.  In a simple picture, we have
$\hbar \delta k = e E \tau$, where $\tau$ is the scattering time.  In a
microscopic theory of resistive charge transport, one can calculate
$\tau$ from scattering theory using, for example, the Born
approximation.  How can one approach this scattering problem from
the perspective of perturbation theory using a suitable
small-parameter expansion?

A small perturbation of the equilibrium configuration corresponds to
a small shift $\delta k$ of the Fermi sea induced by the electric
field $E$.  However, for a given value of the field $E$, a small
shift $\delta k$ corresponds to a large restoring force that
compensates the electric field.  Therefore, the limit of small
shifts $\delta k$ corresponds to strong scattering, that is, the
opposite of a small-parameter expansion. A vanishing shift $\delta k$ corresponds to a perfect insulator requiring infinite scattering.  Often, it is said that
this limiting case requires a large scattering rate $1/\tau$.

Or phrased the other way round: The lowest-order Born approximation
is frequently used as a microscopic model for electric resistivity
due to scattering.  However, the lowest-order Born approximation is
generally most accurate for weak scattering, that is, a large
scattering time $\tau$.  The limiting case of zero scattering corresponds to a perfect conductor with no restoring force acting on the Fermi sea, thus $\delta k \rightarrow \infty$.

Can these apparently conflicting view points be unified?  Is there a
suitable small parameter permitting a perturbative expansion of the
scattering problem that characterizes resistive charge transport in
metals?  Is this discussed anywhere in the literature?

Comment: Calculation of conductivity using the Boltzmann and Born equations usually revolves around expanding in small values of uniform electric field magnitude $E$, i.e. you assume "small fields". See this reference: https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2010/Winter/physics211b/LECTURES/CH01.pdf

Comment: @ArturodonJuan In a linear-response regime, certainly we also assume a weak electric field.  In the language of the Boltzmann equation, my question is about the collision integral.  Take, e.g., Chambers' booklet on "Electrons in Metals and Semiconductors". He discusses collisions in Ch. 8. He uses Fermi's Golden rule [Eq. (8.1)], assuming a "perturbing potential Vs(r) which is not too strong". But this is just the first-order Born approximation in scattering theory.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but perhaps you are interested in the relation between the Boltzmann equation and the Kubo formalism? This is explored here:
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786437508221628
This provides a link between a perturbative framework and Drude-like resistance.